# ¿como realizar una subconsulta en un DB::raw Laravel si tengo contador en ella?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy intentando mostrar todos un contador de establecimientos por categorías, el problema es que algunos de estos establecimientos están bloqueados para determinadas empresas, entonces cuando hago el count me muestra todos los establecimientos así este bloqueados para esa empresa, intento agregar una subconsulta donde este el count y un join que valide que no este en la tabla de restricciones.

adjunto el método:

```
public function categorias($id_empresa){



         $data = DB::table('establecimiento')
         ->where('establecimiento.bloqueado','=',0)
         ->where('categorias.estado','=',1)
        ->join('categorias','categorias.id','=','establecimiento.categorias_id')
        ->select(['categorias.*', 'establecimiento.ciudad',DB::raw('count(categorias_id) as numero_de_establecimientos')])
      ->groupBy('categorias_id')
      ->orderBy('categorias.descripcion', 'asc')
            ->paginate(10);

             return response()->json(compact('data'),200);
    }
```

ese me da como respuesta un json

```
"data": [
            {
                "id": "18",
                "descripcion": "BIENESTAR Y SALUD",
                "img": "http:/public/DnK98bdUuDqB8gLpYz4viEH4FoLjRQarBTbmKV6h.jpeg",
                "estado": "1",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "ciudad": "Bogotá",
                "numero_de_establecimientos": "2"
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "descripcion": "DEPORTES",
                "img": "http:/public/nebP2Icbf5w034KWccdl590PeuK88oUkOdAESZfr.jpeg",
                "estado": "1",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "ciudad": "Bogotá",
                "numero_de_establecimientos": "4"
            }
        ]
```

no muestra el contador y la descripción de la categoría sin restricciones, cuando intento restringirlo con el hay de la otra tabla me genera error, porque no me acepta un `join` en la expresión `raw`,

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes.

1- No uses DB::table o ignoraras todo lo que tengas en tu modelo (eloquent) 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categoria extends Model
{
    //
}
```

2 - Crea las relaciones
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```
    public function establecimientos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Establecimiento::class);
    }
```

3 - Para contar algo usa withCount y si quieres poner un filtro puedes pasarle una función (suena mas difícil de lo que es)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

```
$data = Categoria::withCount(['establecimientos' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('bloqueado',0)->where('estado',1);
}])->get();
```

Ahora unelo todo y tendrás una query de 2 lineas optimizada y reusable